# map.getOrDefault().add() in Java not works

Tags: java, hashmap

The traditional code works well like below:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
if (!map.containsKey(1)) {
   map.put(1, new ArrayList<>());
}
map.get(1).add(2);
```

Now I'd like to try the magic of getOrDefault:

```
map.getOrDefault(1, new ArrayList<>()).add(2);
```

But if I use the above line, then `map.get(1)` is null.

Why?

Comment: Where does it output null?

Comment: map.getOrDefault(1, new ArrayList<>()).add(2);  will output null

Comment: `List.add` returns a `boolean`. What null are we talking about? Are you getting a NullPointerException on `.add(2)` (which would be incredible)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `getOrDefault`, as its name suggests, only gets stuff from the map. It doesn't adds a new KVP to the map. When the key is not present, the default value you pass to `getOrDefault` is returned, but not added to the map, so you'd be adding `2` to an array list that is thrown away immediately.

In other words, this is what your `getOrDefault` code is doing:

```
ArrayList<Integer> value;
if (!map.containsKey(1)) {
    value = new ArrayList<>();
} else {
    value = map.get(1);
}
value.add(2);
```

You should use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) instead. This method actually adds the return value from the function to the map if the key is not present:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(1, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(2);
```

Comment: imo very bad implementation of a good idea: computeIfAbsent does the thing the author wants, but we don't compute a thing when we add a new ArrayList, so the method is doing the things not related to how it's called and it creates confusing code. I prefer to use the tradition version instead, because it does exactly what it looks like it should do.

Answer (score 1):

or you could do:

```
if(!map.contansKey(1)) map.put(1, new ArrayList<>());
map.get(1).add(2);
```

so you can save those lines ;)